# terraform import using name tag for the resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to import the existing resources into Terraform state. But I want to automate the import along with a terraform resource creation script.

I am creating a ELB and 2 instances in existing VPC, so first I have to import the existing VPC into my state file by using the name tag of the VPC. But I am seeing the import is working only by using the id key. Is it possible to import using other parameters apart from ID?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use other tags, you have to use the VPC ID to import your VPC
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/vpc.html
https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html

Comment: Hi Thanks, I did it in different way like writing a script to get the vpc and other resource IDs using aws cli. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using filter field.

e.g.

```
data "aws_vpc" "selected" {
        filter = "tag:name=value"
}
```